# How do I generate a phpdoc for slim framework routes / callbacks

Tags: php, phpdoc, slim

I'm struggling to figure out how I can structure my code such that phpDocumentor will make use of the code blocks.

```
/**
 * GET -- Book, either filtered by id or a full list.
 *
 * @param   SlimApplication     $app    The application object instance.
 * @param   integer             $id The id of the book
 */
$callbackFunction = function($id) use ($app)
{
    //some functionality here.
};
$app->get('/books(/:id)', $callbackFunction );
```

I probably should continue to use the inline `use` statement so I can use `$app`.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

phpDocumentor has no special syntax to document an anonymous function like that.  If you want to document the closure itself, you'd need to actually define it as a first class function, and then you can document it as such.

If knowing that the closure exists and its details need to be known by the documentation reader, presumably it's important enough to be a first class function?  Then again, being a closure, it's not actually available on the code's API... so does it even need to be documented?

Comment: well, the goal is to make an API Doc that auto-generates.

Comment: But what is it that you want the doc to tell the reader about your anonymous function?  Your sample docblock implies that you want the doc to display the closure as if it were a first class function, so that the reader can be aware of its parameter requirements.  However, the reader can't actually write any code to call that closure, so it's just "internal to the code" info anyway.

I guess my main point is that I don't see why a reader of your code's docs *needs* to know about this closure or how it works.  The closest use case I can imagine is a coder-reader that views the source via a link.